# how to set value for a specific cell in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a cell for which i want to its value. I know the cell's column name and its row number (but not its row index)

```
  A B
h 1 2
n 3 4
```

Say, i have dataframe above, i have to change the cell on the first row (i dont know its index 'h') with column name 'B'.

I try `df['B'].iloc[0]=10`, and it works, but it always gives a warning.

```
' SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame'
```

so what is the correct way to change a cell's value for my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixing label and positional indexing requires a little extra work since:

- [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) / [`at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) are designed for labels;
- [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) / [`iat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html) are designed for positional indexing.

You can convert the row positional index to a label:

```
df.at[df.index[0], 'B'] = 10
```

Or you can convert the column label to a positional index:

```
df.iat[0, df.columns.get_loc('B')] = 10
```

**Note**: `at` / `iat` should be preferred to `loc` / `iloc` for fast *scalar* access / setting.

Comment: thank you! another follow-up question: how can i extract one column of the dataframe? i need extracted column can be edited original dataframe. It seems like it will change the original dataframe if i use mycol = df['B]. i.e. if i run mycol.iloc[0]=10, the original first entry in the dataframe will be changed from 1 to 10 as well. How to avoid it? Thank you!

Comment: To work on a copy, use `copy`, e.g. `mycol = df['B'].copy()`. If the above answers your question, please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)  so other users know.